# Change the Binding Path in a TextBlock in a DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, datatemplate

I have a `WPF` `UserControl` that's housed in an element host on a `WindowsForms`.
The `WPF` `UserControl` contains a `ListBox` that uses a `DataTemplate` that has a data bound to a`TextBlock`:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="NewsListBoxTemplate">
        <TextBlock Name="tbTemplate"  Padding="30,0" FontSize="28" 
         Text="{Binding Path=newsE}"  Foreground="Blue"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

The `DataContext` is based on a `DataSet` that gets its data from a sql server database.

I've researched and seen the various answers on SO and can identify the `TextBlock` at run time.  But what I want to do is to change the Binding Path for that `TextBlock` to point to a different field of the `DataSet` when the user makes a choice on the Windows Form at runtime.

There are only two database fields available as choices.

From the point where I've identified the `TextBlock` name as tbTemplate, can anyone suggest code I can use to switch between the two Paths?

Comment: Can you eloborate more on what you mean by - 'when the user makes a choice on the Windows Form at runtime.'? Do you mean selecting different row on the list box or something else? What exactly the user is selecting?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [BindingOperations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingoperations%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#fbid=Qdsuk75GYwl)

```
BindingOperations.SetBinding(tbTemplate, TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding("MyProperty"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the [link..](http://mobile.dzone.com/articles/how-access-named-control)  to get the control with its name from the `DataTemplate` and do the binding for that...

```
tbTemplate.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding("PropertyName"));
```